# Morphology from Magick++ to match Command line Convert

Tags: c++, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I am trying to duplicate the ImageMagick command line:

```
Convert In.jpg ( -bias 50% -morphology Convolve LoG:0x1.5 ) Out.jpg
```

via the Magick++ in C++ (visual Studio 2010 Express)

I have read that the morphological operations are not part of Magic++ so the *C* MagickCore functions need to be used. I am unable to obtain output that matches (or is even close) to
ImageMagick command line output.

I am attempting to create the Kernel via

```
k=MagickCore::AcquireKernelInfo("LoG:0x1.5");
```

and execute the morphology via

```
m = MagickCore::MorphologyImage(i, MagickCore::ConvolveMorphology, 3, k, e);
```

I am guessing at these methods and parameters due to lack of information on specifics.
Does anyone have guidance on how to accomplish the same output from C++ ?

Comment: The default value for the number of iterations is 1. You should use 1 instead of 3.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. That parameter was not obvious from the intellisense popup that simply listed 'ssize_t' or from the stackoverflow question: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8980165/morphology-using-magick
That post is the only information I could find concerning morphological operations from Magick++.
I did see a function in the ImageMagick source library that specifies an 'interation' argument but that was for function  MagickMorphologyImage(MagickWand *wand, MorphologyMethod method,const ssize_t iterations,KernelInfo *kernel), the signature was close but...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To accomplish these operations in Magick++ would require many tedious steps that I have no documentation on. The kernel creation is especially dubious as it came out as 13x13.

I found another way to accomplish the same goal: Use the MagickCore::ConvertImageComand(). The parameters are the same as the command line version and the output is the same. Using the command from C++ seems to work without problems...

using namespace Magick;
char *args[]={"convert", "In.jpg","(","-bias","50%","-morphology", "convolve", "LoG:0x1.5", ")","Out.jpg" };
   int args_count = 10;

```
MagickCore::ExceptionInfo *exception = MagickCore::AcquireExceptionInfo();
MagickCore::ImageInfo *image_info = MagickCore::AcquireImageInfo();
(void) strcpy(image_info->filename,"In.jpg");
image = MagickCore::ReadImage(image_info, exception);
  MagickBooleanType status =
   ConvertImageCommand(image_info, args_count, args, NULL, exception);
```

I would prefer to have this operation result in a buffer or in-memory image rather than writing to the disk but I guess that is another question...

Answer (score 0):

The next version of ImageMagick (6.8.8-7) will have support for morphology in the Magick++ API. Your command:

```
convert In.jpg -bias 50% -morphology Convolve LoG:0x1.5 Out.jpg
```

can be written like this:

```
Magick::Image img;

img.read("In.jpg");
img.artifact("convolve:bias", "50%");
img.morphology(ConvolveMorphology, LoGKernel, "0x1.5");
img.write("Out.jpg");
```